# how to find the position of string search in a json array column in laravel

Tags: sql, json, laravel

i have a query which returns boolean value from a json array column about whether the string i am searching exists or not

the column is something liek this   ------   ["a","b","c"]
and the query is below

```
DB::table('product_lines as l')->where('l.id',$position->product_line_id)
 ->whereRaw('json_contains(l.types, \'["b"]\')')->first()->count();
```

but i want to get the position where the string was found... lets say for this it should return 1.

please help.

Comment: Aren't you getting the count of such rows where your condition gets satisfied? And the question is to get the position for that string for every row that satisfies the condition?

Comment: no not every raw...imagine i am using first and it returns one raw in that condition where i need to search the position..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pl = DB::table('product_lines as pl')
                     ->select(DB::raw('JSON_SEARCH(pl.types, "one", "b") as 
                           idx'))
                     ->where('id', $position->product_line_id)
                     ->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(pl.types, \'"b"\', \'$\')')
                     ->first();
dd($pl->idx);
```

It will give you the output as `"$[1]"` `""` are part of the output string. So you
need to get the number between `[]` to get the index of the item in the array.

OR

```
$pl = DB::table('product_lines as pl')
                     ->where('id', $position->product_line_id)
                     ->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(pl.types, \'"b"\', \'$\')')
                     ->first();

$arr = json_decode($pl->types);

dd(array_search("b", $arr));
```

Comment: so this "array_search" function is what i forgot and have been trying to remember the name of the function. this is what works perfectly..anyway. Thanks Aashish.. i guess your second example should work perfectly, u may remove the first one or place the second example at first. that's more appropriate

Comment: Yeah, you could use that but if you want to do it in the query, you can go with the first option :)

Comment: In case the solution solved your problem, acceptance of the answer is desirable :)